# ¿Se puede trabajar usando JSF sin la necesidad de un Framework?

Tags: java, web, jsf

Quizá la pregunta sea trivial o incluso no muy bien detallada de forma técnica, así que replanteo el caso:
Soy primerizo en desarrollo web, todo el tiempo he estado acostumbrado a jalar/arrastrar elementos de la paleta de elementos a un formulario de escritorio.

Ahora estoy aprendiendo tecnología JSF pero me resulta un poco difícil seguir los tutoriales de mi catedrático ya que dentro del contenido se entremezclan códigos de funcionalidad del diseño y estética junto con la lógica de la aplicación.

Primero quiero aprender como funciona JSF en la lógica de una aplicación. Como pasar parámetros, validarlos, cargar formularios, enviar datos de un formulario a otro, etc... ¿Es posible hacerlo sin escatimar tanto en el área del diseño? Y si es así, ¿De qué manera? ¿Cómo construir formularios web de una forma fácil?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con escatimar en el área de diseño? Si usabas un editor WYSIWYG (visual), deberías acostumbrarte a no usarlo: la manera más eficiente de crear HTML es escribir el código directamente (lo que no implica que no uses herramientas de autocompletado).